# Pascal's triangle expression not resulting in correct output

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking for help with some code I have written for Project Euler Problem 148.

The problem is as follows:

Find the number of entries which are not divisible by 7 in the first one billion rows of Pascal's triangle.

I am aware that this specific method will not work as it will - when ran with 1000000000 - result in an overflow error.

Regardless, I am curious why this code does not work:

I use the expression `((math.factorial(r))/((math.factorial(t))*(math.factorial((r-t)))))` to find the value of the term at the given row and term, as shown by the formula:

[image: formula]

When numrows == 7, the script should print 0, which it does.

When numrows == 100, the script should print 2361, but my code prints 3139.

The code is as follows:

```
import math

numrows = 100
count = 0

for r in range(numrows):
  for t in range(r):
    if not (((math.factorial(r))/((math.factorial(t))*(math.factorial((r-t))))) % 7 == 0):
      count += 1
print(count)
```

Comment: Are you sure the formula is correct? This might be a better question for [math.se].

Comment: Also, the values of `t` go from 0 to r, and you only go up to (r-1). This way, you miss one value on each row (and as they all are `1`, they should be counted.)

Answer (score 2):

You incorrectly implemented the formula, using float division `/` instead of integer division '//'.  With the change to

```
    if not math.factorial(r)//(math.factorial(t)*math.factorial(r-t)) % 7 == 0:
```

You get the output `2261`.  (Yes, I removed the superfluous parentheses.)

With small numbers, you get exact results in floating-point arithmetic, so your modulus operation yields the desired result.  However, when you get up to the lower rows, you run into the limits of floating-point precision -- the result of the division won't be *exactly* `blahblah.0`, and your `== 0` comparison fails.  Thus, you count quite a few cells that aren't supposed to match your criterion.

Finally, add `Thierry's` repair:

```
for t in range(r+1):
```

... and you get `2361`, as desired.

---

Note that this nested loop will not solve the problem in reasonable time.  You need to attack this with an analysis of divisibility: how many factors of 7 do you have in the numerator and denominator?  If the numerator has more, then the result is divisible by 7.

Use the truncated quotient of `r / 7^n` for n from 1 to `r log 7`.  Do the same for `t` and `t-r`.  You can also adjust a running count of 7s as you iterate over the needed values.

Comment: There are still 100 missing values, see my comment on the question.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille: right; you got to that repair before I did.